# Using Bootstrap and working with Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I am using Carousel to display a few pictures. I have it all in place and the first picture shows, however when you click the right and left Chevron's it doesn't take you to the next picture.

I am a little new to HTML / CSSl and definitely Bootstrap. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks. My Carousel code is below.

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/type.jpg" alt="typewriter">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>The Header</h3>
        <p>Header Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/pad.jpg" alt="scratchpad">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second Header</h3>
        <p>Second Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/screen.jpg" alt="monitor">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third Header</h3>
        <p>Third Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your code is correctly working check this link http://www.bootply.com/XKU3JuSDnn. and check Roko answer also.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot the bootstrap js file. can you include your header as well?

Make sure you have a link to [bootstrap js](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) (as well as [css](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)) in the html header

From the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't have it. I added it but no difference. I'm a little lost as to what else it would be.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Hello World!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

Comment: @Kane updated answer.- no 'https' in your comment header.
Also- maybe add the header in the question itself, with proper format

Comment: thanks for your help. I added the bootstrap js and css links. The first image shows on load, but when I hit the left or right arrow it does not go to the next image.

Comment: cycling pictures, I noticed my address bar goes from index.html to index.html#carousel-example-generic. Also, the page moves down just below the navigation bar and the first image still shows.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had a syntax error in the code.